# Unable to configure a standalone Gremlin Server to work with JanusGraph

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I followed the instruction to configure a standalone gremlin to work with Janusgraph using the documentation: http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/server.html. I am not able to download the jars using the command mentioned in the document.

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh -i org.janusgraph janusgraph-all $VERSION
```

It fails with the following error message:

> Could not install the dependency: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.sleepycat#je;7.3.7: not found]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.sleepycat#je;7.3.7: not found]
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.getDependencies(GrapeIvy.groovy:424)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:571)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:534)
>       at groovy.grape.Grape.resolve(Grape.java:202)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber.copyDependenciesToPath(DependencyGrabber.groovy:124)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber.copyDependenciesToPath(DependencyGrabber.groovy:77)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.GremlinServerInstall.main(GremlinServerInstall.java:38)

Also, I also followed the instruction to setup a grapeConfig.xml. Here is how it looks :

```
    <ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="central" root="http://central.maven.org/maven2/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="jitpack" root="https://jitpack.io" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

I am using janusgraph version 0.2.0.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Generally there's no need to install JanusGraph into a separate Gremlin Server. The JanusGraph distribution already contains a Gremlin Server at the appropriate TinkerPop version that is ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there's no need to install JanusGraph into a separate Gremlin Server. The JanusGraph distribution already contains a Gremlin Server at the appropriate Apache TinkerPop version that is ready for use (JanusGraph 0.2.0 uses Apache TinkerPop 3.2.6). You can start the Gremlin Server using the `bin/gremlin-server.sh` script.

If you still want to install JanusGraph into a standalone Gremlin Server, you need to update the `grapeConfig.xml` to include the Oracle repository, which contains the `com.sleepycat` artifacts for Oracle BerkeleyDB Java Edition:

```
<ibiblio name="oracle" root="http://download.oracle.com/maven" m2compatible="true"/>
```